# How to save Live Streams running wowza server on compute engine to google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, wowza

Firstly, I am running wowza media server on google computing host. I am trying to achieve a scenario were live streams can be stored directly to google cloud storage.

Secondly, how do i edit/update a text file on computing host using a python script?